# Google Functions trigger

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-photos-api

I have created website displaying pictures from defined album in Google Photos. For better performance picture URLs are read from local database. Database is updated in the background after user requested initial page.

Is there any possibility to use Google Functions to trigger service updating local database after specified photo album were updated?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your current setup is this:

- youraccount@gmail.com is connected with Google Photos service.
- Website that is connected to specific album in Google Photos from youraccount@gmail.com
- Local database that is running on your local computer and contains the URLs of your photos. So when user request your main page the site is reading the URLs from the database and displays the photos from that album.

If understood correctly you want a Google Cloud Function that updates the URL list in the local database, whenever a photo is uploaded in Google Photos album.

Google Cloud Functions can be triggered with various events and currently there are no events associated with Google Photos album update that can trigger a Cloud Function. I assume that you are not uploading photos using Google Photos API, otherwise you would just get the URL at the spot and update directly the database.

The only solutions that I can see are:

1. Instead of using the Google Photos page to upload photos to the album. Implement the update through a website's page using the [Google Photos APIs](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media). Currently it is supported in Java and PHP. Then at the same time just update the local database.
2. You know the frequency of when the photos are uploaded. e.g. Once every 1 hour there can be an upload, or once per day there can be an update. So you can use Cloud Scheduler to deploy scheduled Cron jobs. Each job will be responsible to check the album's photos and at the same time to compare the photos with the saved URLs. If the URL exists then skip it otherwise add it. You can have the Cron job running every once in a while, depending on how frequently there is a photo upload to the album.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I cannot use your proposal. This site will present photos of my friend, who want to update his portfolio as simply as possible. Simplest way is to shoot a photo with smartphone which can automatically synchronize device photo library with Google Photos and the only activity my friend should do is decide if new photo should be presented on his site - put new photo to album.

Comment: I've been searching for Google Functions Storage Triggers but could not find what I'm looking for.

Comment: I understand. So you have to go with option 2 which is having a Cron Job running and checking the album with Google Photos API and then updating the local database. For the supported events in Google Cloud Functions you can find at [Cloud Functions > Events and Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers#triggers). For Cloud Storage you will use the **Google Cloud Storage** event trigger.